# Docker volume sharing between container and host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a local Ubuntu repository with debmirror using Docker. I would like to store the downloaded files in a directory called `./repo` on the host machine

The container is able to download files into the container which I can confirm with `docker exec <container_id>...`, but the files don't get reflected in the `./repo` directory on the host machine.

```
$ docker ps 
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS            PORTS     NAMES
2338e107050e    21b98483ec19      "/bin/sh -c '/bin/..."   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes               admiring_kirch

$ docker exec 2338e107050e ls -lF /repo
total 12
-r--r--r-- 1 root root   15 Aug 17 08:13 Archive-Update-in-Progress-f502fa9e2b7d
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Aug 17 08:15 dists/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 17 08:23 pool/

$ ls -lF ./repo/ 
total 0
```

These are my `docker-compose.yml` configurations.

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml 
version: '2'
services:
    debmirror:
        build: ./app
        container_name: "debmirror"
        volumes:
            - repo:/repo
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true

volumes:
    repo:
```

These are my `Dockerfile` configurations.

```
$ cat app/Dockerfile 
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ENV http_proxy "http://proxy.example.com:80/"
ENV https_proxy "http://proxy.example.com:80/"

RUN mkdir -p /app/mirrorkeyring \
    && chown -R root:www-data /app \
    && chmod -R 755 /app

RUN mkdir /repo \
    && chown -R root:www-data /repo \
    && chmod -R 571 /repo

VOLUME /repo

RUN apt update && apt install -y debmirror xz-utils
COPY mirrorbuild.sh /app/mirrorbuild.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/mirrorbuild.sh

RUN gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /app/mirrorkeyring/pubring.gpg --import /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg
RUN gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /app/mirrorkeyring/trustedkeys.gpg --import /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

RUN /bin/bash -c /app/mirrorbuild.sh
```

Any ideas why I don't see any files in the `./repo` directory on the host machine?

Answer (score 0):

Change your docker compose as below to make it available on `./repo` of the host -

```
version: '2'
services:
    debmirror:
        build: ./app
        container_name: "debmirror"
        volumes:
            - ${PWD}/repo:/repo
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
```

Basically, when you define a volume in compose file it creates a named volume which you can see by doing `docker volume ls` the volume data stays on the host `/var/lib/docker` container volume/data directory. Using this you can share same data across multiple containers.

But, if you want to see data on the host machine inside some specific folder, you got to use host bind/mount volumes as I have suggest above in compose file.

Comment: Now I'm able to see the same data on the host machine but not in the `./repo` directory. How do I see the same data in `./repo` directory?

Comment: ./repo directory of container or host? In container it will be available in /repo as defined in volumes.

Comment: I see data in `/repo` in the container but I would like to see data also in `./repo` on the host.

Comment: Recreate the containers, try to put a test file manually inside container & see if it reflects on the host. You should be able to see it at `./repo` from where you did a `docker-compose up -d`. Good luck!